# Google map is not working with Angular App

Tags: angularjs

Below code of google map is not working in live Application using Angularjs.locally it is working.but when I upload to the live App it is not working there, and when i install Intel XDK Device plugin get an error like the given plugin was depreciate.how to solve..?

index.html

```
   <div class="item item-divider" style="font-size:18px;">
                            <i class="icon ion-map"></i> &nbsp;
                            <a ng-click="launchGoogleMaps()">Location map</a>
                        </div>
```

app.js

```
  $scope.launchGoogleMaps=function(){
        var url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?ll="+$scope.temple.latitude+","+$scope.temple.longitude;
intel.xdk.device.launchExternal(url);
    }
```

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: Got an error like intel is not defined.so I installed Intel XDK Device plugin.but the same error occur.and when I install Intel XDK Device plugin the plugin shows waring like depreciate Intel XDK Device plugin @berentrom

Comment: @berentrom can you help me to solve the issue ?